# Browsersync within Vagrant VM does not properly proxy

Tags: node.js, apache2, vagrant, gulp, browser-sync

I'm having an issue where browser-sync is not properly proxying my apache2 server. I'm running browser-sync through gulp within an Ubuntu 14.04 VM with Ubuntu 15.04 on the host. I'm using the following configuration:

```
browserSync({
    proxy: 'localhost:80',
    port: '8081',
    open: false
});
```

The guest machine's port 80 is mapped to 8080 on the host. The gulp task runs without issue and I get the expected output from browser-sync. If I visit localhost:8081/index.php, it works without any issue. If I try to visit localhost:8081/foo/index.php, however, my browser is redirecting to localhost:8080/foo/index.php, and browser-sync does not function.

If I set logLevel to debug, I see output when I visit localhost:8081/index.php:

[BS] Browser Connected: Chrome, version: 45.0.2454.85

There is no output, however, when I visit localhost:8081/foo/index.php

Is there a bug with browser-sync when used within a VM?